# How to restrict acces on application store

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile-application

My problems is that I develop an application for android and IOS, but i want it to only be accessible from people I choose.

For android, I can do it using the testing mode of application, but i want a solution more simple for users, which are not really comfortable with developing.

For IOS, the only solution i found is using TestFlight, but once again if I can avoid using third party application it'll be better for users.

Moreover I wish I could update the user list easily.

Thanks.

Comment: For android you can just send the users the APK file, or if you do want the app on the app stores the best thing to do would be some kind of login screen to stop unauthorized users.

Comment: Ok thanks, sending the APK is a solution I used but it is necessary to use a third-party app to download it, and so for IOS there is no way to do somethings like that apart using TestFlight?

Answer (score 1):

You can manage access on your application logic, user management system, and your backend/APIs, Google Play and Apple App-store are publically available and except for general geographical and regulatory filtration (like country base, or age-based limitations), there is no other way to limit access to it.

You can simply add access management to your app logic and include the limitation in your app page in the marketplace so people don't download your app and leave bad reviews! ( which will happen for sure anyways! )